# What is the difference between a balanced and unbalanced mono jack?

Tags: console

My Behringer Xenyx 1202 FX has "Balanced or Unbalanced Jacks". In addition the answer to [this previous question](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/5159/501) reference both. What's the difference between the two types of Mono Jacks.

Answer (score 12):

If we're talking about 1/4" 'phone jack' patch cables, you can easily tell the difference by the number of conductors on the plug.

2-conductor cables are **unbalanced**, and can be identified by the "tip/sleeve" configuration of conductors on the plug. You can call this "TS" for short:
[image: 1/4" TS connector]

In contrast, a 3-conductor cable is **balanced**, and can be identified by the "tip/ring/sleeve" configuration, or "TRS":
[image: 1/4" TRS connector]

An audio signal is a waveform provided by a change in voltage. That voltage needs to be relative to some other signal--most commonly a ground. Within a closed system you could use a single conductor to transmit this voltage relative to the the common ground of the system, but if you are connecting two different pieces of hardware, you need at minimum two conductors for a mono signal - one for ground, and one for voltage.

In a stereo signal, you need at minimum three conductors: one for ground, and then one for the voltage of each channel. When we are sending a signal relative only to ground, the line is referred to as **unbalanced**. Unbalanced lines are more susceptible to picking up interference, especially over large cable runs.

So, if we're talking about audio cables, the 1/4" TS can ONLY carry unbalanced mono signals. The 1/4" TRS is capable of carrying unbalanced stereo signals. However, the 1/4" TRS can ALSO be used for *balanced* mono signals. This requires a hot AND cold for the signal, IN ADDITION to ground.

If you examine a microphone XLR cable, you will notice that it too has three conductors. Microphones should ALWAYS use balanced cables due to the nature of the long cable runs. You can easily find 1/4" TRS to XLR adapters, since they are used for mono signals in the same way. Also keep in mind that if you plug a balanced cable into a jack that only accepts unbalanced connections, the signal will still work, but the entire line will be unbalanced since only two conductors are being used.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question as it was worded ("difference between the two types of Mono **Jacks**"), but I think it would be rather natural to also explain what balanced audio actually is, or at least link to [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balanced_audio).   "This requires a hot AND cold for the signal" hardly does the trick, the common names "hot and cold" are not only unprecise but also really misleading on their own.

Comment: I've answered to my level of expertise! Thanks for the Wiki link--feel free to add whatever else you feel is necessary!

Comment: This description and explanation is excelent easy to understand thanks mate, you rock! must be a teacher :)

Comment: NReilingh's answer was very on point. Thanks..I signed up just to thank you cuz Ive been frustrated talking to so many people who cant explain such a thing to me in a way that i understand what the heck is going on. Ive been doing a lot of chasing my tail because of the misinformed who seem to always thinkt he answer is spending $100 more dollars on something else all the while not having an answer to such a simple equation that deals with complications via balanced and unbalanced cables and the issues that can come up with switching them about(such as the grainy high range vocals Im 99% sure